# How to make JSF Primefaces Tree expandable

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, tree, expandable

Is it possible that all tree nodes expandable by default at the beginning?Because i bring data when i click the expand icon.

```
FiderRepository fiderRepository = ConversationManager
                .getInstance().applicationContext
                .getBean(FiderRepository.class);
         FiderUtil fiderUtil=(FiderUtil) event.getTreeNode().getData();


     if(fiderUtil.getId()!=null){
     Integer parentId = fiderUtil.getId();
     SearchParameters parameters=new SearchParameters();
     parameters.setNamedQuery("Fider.findChildren");
     parameters.addNamedQueryParameter("parentId", parentId);
     if(parentId!=null){
     List<Fider> fiderler = fiderRepository.find(parameters);
     for (Fider fider : fiderler) {
         TreeNode node=new DefaultTreeNode();
    node=new DefaultTreeNode(new FiderUtil(fider.getAdi(),fider.getId()), event.getTreeNode());
}
     }}
```

This is my `onNodeExpand` method.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear. But if you want all nodes to be expanded by default, you can do it by calling the "setExpanded(boolean expanded)" method on every TreeNode during construction of the Tree.

Refer : http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/4.0/org/primefaces/model/TreeNode.html

Comment: Also please format the code, as it will be easier to read. Right now for others it will be hard to even understand the question.